# Proxy is not working after build -React.js

Tags: reactjs, proxy

After building the react app proxy is not working

and this is my **package.json**

```
"proxy": {
    "/customer": {
      "target": "http://my-ip:8081"
    },
    "/loan": {
      "target": "http://my-ip:8081"
    }
  },
```

Comment: what sort of error are you getting if any?

Comment: Isn't proxy just for the development server? the build folder is just static assets